# Protect or Hide .Net webservices calls and response in Fiddler

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-services, iis, server

In `.Net` web-service hosting the `IIS` and used for the desktop  application while login the app the person track and see all the input calls to service and response back into app.

Then analysis the issue and go through google and got solutions. to make `HTTPS` or `ssl` in `webservice url`.also encrypt and decrypt also doing both client and server side.

after that i check with `fiddler` they also tracking the web services call and responses .even they can able to break and run the app using this.

I was tired and make the protect the `webservice` calls. and unable to achieve the what i need.

I also attached screenshot below for your reference.

Guys plz help me...if any otherway to protect the service calls in Fiddler.

Answer (score 1):

I see no screenshot. But if I understood correctly then you are saying that fiddler can decrypt your traffic.

Well that is because fiddler imports fake certificates into windows certificate store and then proxies data through itself. That is why it can actually decrypt data. I don't really see a point to try to protect web calls from Fiddler. But you can force direct connection and try not to use proxies with your application. But then again... you won't be able to use **any** proxies